# Data loss after USB pen drive used on Android phone

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, android, file-corruption

I have been using a Kingston 32GB OTG USB device (pic-1) on my Samsung J1 Ace, for some time now. Today I plugged it to the phone and moved several folders to the USB drive. Then I plugged it to my laptop. But all the old files and folders in the USB were lost, except for those folders that were moved from the phone.

I have posted a screenshot (pic-2) of how the folder looks like when the USB pen drive is opened from the laptop (it’s the same when opened from the phone as well).

Can someone please explain what happened and how to recover the folders (hopefully)?

pic-1
[image: Kingston 32GB OTG USB device]

---

pic-2
[image: screenshot of USB pen drive opened from the laptop]

Comment: If you go to folder option and untick try hide files and folder extensions all of them does the content change or remains the same ?

Comment: Yes. I already tried that. No change.

Comment: All they show is 0kb I'm very confused is there any files with different sizes or they're all 0kb of there aren't files with any more sizes what's the used disk space on the USB ?

Comment: You should try one of those programs that scan the whole disk and try to recognize files by the contents, like TestDisk

Comment: The folders I copied last from the phone are there and all of it is accessible without any errors. I've lost only the folders which were there before I attempted copying folders from the phone.

Comment: Navigate to your drive letter from command prompt and type the following : attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.* replace g: with your drive letter

Comment: If the above doesn't work I think it might cause the same issue like when you use a USB on mac and windows doesn't read the format anymore btw can you still see your folders when you plug your USB into your phone ?

Comment: I tried the attrib command as well. No use.!!!
 
I checked the USB on my phone and on another Android phone (different Samsung model). It is same as the laptop.!!!

Comment: https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm

Comment: Hannu: Tried the software; not useful.!!!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshot of the contents directory, it looks like you pulled it before it was done writing, and corrupted the file system.

This is not unusual, and is why many OSs have an "eject" procedure to perform before pulling the drive out.

Format the USB drive, and restore the files from backup.

Comment: Well, all the moved folders are there in the USB (which means the move is completed without any interruptions!). 

Unfortunately I don't have backups of those folders!

Comment: You could try your OS's disk/file system check utilities, and perhaps try some data recovery software, but honestly, I'd say you're pretty much out of luck.  Take away: Make backups.

Comment: I ran Windows error check. It results no errors!